# Apache ur rewrite not working when given a condition

Tags: apache

I  have written code like

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule $1 !mobile
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /mobile [R,L]
```

i wnat the url to have /mobile if it did not find mobile as 1st parameter like www.abc.com/mobile but this code does not work, i.e. the second line does not work. Is it correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you want a **`RewriteCond`** and not a `RewriteRule` for your condition:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !mobile
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /mobile [R,L]
```